# Problem with CanActivate guards when initialNavigation: 'enabled'

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-universal

I have angular universal app where part of routes is protected by CanActivate guard, where canActivate method use services to protect the route. But with initialNavigation: "enabled" config my guards didn't work. 
As I suppose, this issue is faced because of:

> The initial navigation starts before the root component is created. 
>   The bootstrap is blocked until the initial navigation is complete.
>   ( from angular docs )

The question is: how can I use services in canActivate guard with initialNavigation - enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by "guards didn't work"? I did use guards calling services with `initialNavigation` set to `enabled` in one of my projects and it did work

Comment: CanActivate Method in my guard looks like:
`canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this._statusService
    .userStatusObservable
    .pipe(
      map(status => {
        if(status.is_authenticated && status.is_customer) {
          return true;
        } else if(!status.is_authenticated) {
          setTimeout(() => this._router.navigate([]));
          return false;
        }
        }
      })
    );
}`

and maybe it does not work because of  **The bootstrap is blocked until the initial navigation is complete.**

Comment: My mistake, I block request at this service by using something like `if( isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId) ) return null`

thanks all for answering

Answer (score 1):

I think @Yuriy Kovalets already found his problem.

But for future reference, for anyone who might have similar problem, as I had.

My application was working well until I set **initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'** because of SSR.
Pages/routes that didn't have *canActivate* set still work well, and the application bootstrap. Then if I navigate to another page that have *canActivate* set it works.

The problem was when I try to enter directly (put the url into the browser) to pages/routes that have *canActivate* set.

This is my canActivate RouteGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class SecurityRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

    userIsLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private router: Router, private securityService: SecurityService) {
        this.userIsLoggedIn = of(false);
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
            let userState = this.securityService.getUserState();
            this.userIsLoggedIn = of(userState.isLoggedIn);

            return this.userIsLoggedIn.pipe(map(userIsLoggedIn => {
                if (userIsLoggedIn) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('lastRequiredURL',state.url);
                    this.securityService.loginUser();
                    return false;
                }
            }))

    }

}
```

As one can see, it depends on *SecurityService* to validate if user is authenticated or not.

What I found out was that this *SecurityService* wasn't initialized when I set **initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'** and so the user wasn't redirect to login page as should be.

This happen because my *SecurityService* was initialized at *ngOnInit()* of my **app.component.ts**.
With **initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'** the navigation and the *canActivate* runs before **app.component.ts**.

My solution was to move *SecurityService* initialization from **app.component.ts** to **APP_INITIALIZER** set at *app.module.ts* like this:

```
export function appSecurityInitializer(securityService: SecurityService) {
  // SecurityService initialization
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    }),
    CommonAppModule,
    SecurityModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appSecurityInitializer,
      deps: [SecurityService],
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you provided, I could only get into a little of data.

I think what you need is to set some routes, to be protected with can activate, and some other without the route guard.

You can do something like this.

```
{path: 'secure-path', component: 'SomeSecureComponent', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'not-a-secure-path', component: 'SomeNonSecureComponent'},
```

You can do something like this to get rid of the route guard in the insecure pages, just don't provide them.

If you think I got your question wrong, please let me know, because this is what i understood from the little information you provided.

Comment: Thanks, but I already do this, and this works as well, without initialNavigation option for routes config. But when i set initialNavigation as "enabled" - my protected routes dont load.

Comment: can you just let me know how your routes array looks like. I may can answer better if so.

Comment: I have app.routing.module with next config:  

`@NgModule({  
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routing, {initialNavigation: 'enabled'})],  
    exports: [RouterModule],  
   providers: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard]  
})  
  
export class AppRoutingModule { }`  
  
and _routing_ array looks like:  

`const routing: Routes = [  
    {  
      path: '',  
      loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'  
    },  
    {  
      path: 'orders',  
      loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule',  
      canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard]  
    }  
];`

Comment: and /orders route did not load with current RouterModule configuration

sorry for bad formatting

Comment: From what i know, you are using angular app for SSR server side rendering. So the issue is that the page that the URL corresponds is not yet rendered when the application makes request to the same. In my knowledge, the only way you can handle this is through an errorHandler which handles all the failed url requests. you can set yuor default errorHandler in the forRoot itself. see this link https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#errorHandler for details on error handlers.

Comment: It means that I cant use route guards when initial navigation enabled?

Comment: I guess so. I think the security should be handled by your back-end here